# Display records from multiple table in PDO mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Want to print Participant information like firstName, organization from two different table. Query is working properly as it is giving desired results. But when I try to print fetched data, it returns an error.

```
function get_all_participant(){
  include 'connection.php';

  $sql = '
select p1.fname
     , p1.organization
     , p1.state
     , p2.created
  from participant p1
     INNER JOIN programme_participant p2 
 ON p1.id = p2.participant_id
';
  try{
    $results = $db->prepare($sql);
    $results->execute();
  } catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Error! " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    return false;
  }
  return $results->fetch();
```

}

```
<?php foreach (get_all_participant() as $item){
         echo $item['fname'];
  }?>
```

Output(error):

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'fname'

Comment: what does `get_all_participant()` return?

Comment: you don't understand. What is the result from the array `get_all_participant()`

Comment: It returns participant information.
`return $results->fetch();`

Comment: is the array empty?

Comment: Incidentally, we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992. Join us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
$result = $results->fetchAll();
```

if query return multiple records then fetch function will not work

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.